# How can I make a third party Vue library have access to other third-party Vue plugins being used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, syncfusion

Let's say I'm using vuex, vue-i18n, and Syncfusion ej2-vue-grids in a project.

My app will have access to $store and $t, but if I make a grid and define a custom template for a column, the component that gets rendered in that field does not have access to vuex or vue-i18n.

I've been able to get around this for vuex by setting `Vue.prototype.$store = store;` when first setting up the Vue app. vue-i18n has several additional properties, though, and setting everything on the prototype feels like a hack.

I assume Syncfusion must be calling `Vue.extend` when creating the components for the grid column, so the component is losing all context from the app. Is this a bug on their side, or is there something I should be doing differently?

***EDIT***
Here is a plnkr with an example of the behavior I'm seeing.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XwVC6yNQaI2vQIUoWfSm?p=preview

When you first view it, the Freight column should be empty (because it can't access the store) and below the grid should be a line of !!!!!!!! (because it *can* access the store).

If you uncomment line 15 in `index.js`, both of line of !!!!!! below the grid and the contents of the Freight column should be visible.

Comment: Plugins already extend `Vue.prototype` when attaching to them. Show us some code. Or, maybe, a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: I added an example to the body of my question. https://plnkr.co/edit/XwVC6yNQaI2vQIUoWfSm?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
We need to pass the store and vue-i18n reference to the template declaration.AS in below code snippet.
<pre>
<code>
   tmpl() {
        return {
          template: {
            store,
             i18n,
            data() {
              return {
                data: {}
              }
            },
            computed: {
              test() {
                return this.$store.state.test;
              }`enter code here`
            },
            template: `<div>
   <div> Translated text child: {{ $t("message.hello") }}</div>
<span>{{ test }} {{ data.Freight }} {{ test }}</span> </div>`
          }
        }
      }
</code>
</pre>
```

Plunker sample with updated column template using store: https://plnkr.co/edit/Sei9F1MEvNyLGseZEzM1?p=preview